# Drag and drop of QDockWidget between two or more windows

Tags: qt

I would like to know if anybody knows if it is possible to drag a [QDockWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdockwidget.html) from one window to another.

I am developping an application that has a lot of windows. Each of these windows has a specific usage. I want to use QDockWidget because of the automatic rescaling when docking a widget in the main window. But I would also like to have the possibility to have a new dock area in a new window so that I can put together all the widgets related one to each other.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot drag a `QDockWidget` from one application to another if they are developed separately.

On the other hand, I think that you can **reparent** a `QDockWidget` to another `QMainWindow`, only if it's part of the same application.

...aaaaand you can always try to **intercept** the drap/drop events and pass information between the two windows with a protocol of your own: define a new mime type for the drag and define the syntax of the data associated to the `QDockWidget`. Then, implement the code to analyze the data and reconstruct the contents of the `QDockWidget` in the target window... not an *easy* task!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Fèlix, `dock->setParent(otherQMainWindow);` is a way to do it.