# Dock widgets within main window and parent widget

Tags: c++, qt, qdockwidget

I am making a small Qt application. Main Window has dock sites and child mdi windows also have dock sites. The problem is that I can't move child windows' dock widgets to main windows' dock sites. Is there is a workaround for this problem? Child mdi windows are also of QMainWindow class.

Comment: This could be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723765/drag-and-drop-of-qdockwidget-between-two-or-more-windows, http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/41847-Dragging-QDockWidgets-between-QMainWindows (the latter one did not work for me out-of-the-box, since the `enterEvent` of the main window is not called during the drag operation)

Comment: @Andreas it seems to me that I can try the approach of the second link. Thank you.